# Internal parameter for Protected method on Public Abstract class

Tags: c#

I have a `public abstract class` that has its constructor marked as `internal`. This makes the class visible outside but only inheritable inside the assembly. Now I want to add a `protected` method that takes an `internal class` parameter. This sounds possible, since there is no way an outside class can inherit the abstract class due to the constructor restriction; hence, the method will be used only internally and only by child classes; as a result the parameter class reference will remain strictly inside the assembly.

However, I get the venerable error:

> Error CS0051 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'X' is less accessible than method 'Y.Do(X)'

Here's the code:

```
namespace SomeNamespace.One
{
    public abstract class Y
    {
        internal Y()
        { }

        protected void Do(Two.X x)
        { }
    }

}

namespace SomeNamespace.Two
{
    internal abstract class X
    { }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Any suggestions (beside making Do() `internal`)?

Edit: Changed the code to use namespaces - now it will not compile :)

Comment: What's wrong with making Do internal out of interest? Also bear in mind that in that class you might create a class that inherits from this that has a public constructor and that could then be inherited by a class outside of this assembly which would then be able to access your protected method.

Comment: Try to mark it `internal protected` instead

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729251/how-to-limit-subclassing-of-public-abstact-class-to-types-in-same-assembly-and-t?rq=1 seems related to your question.

Comment: Yup, that looks the same to me. One option is to make the *class* internal, but make it implement a public interface, btw.

Comment: I have just tried this on .Net 4.5.2 on VS2015 and it compiles without errors

Comment: @Chris, Yep question is the same. I could not find it in the searches I did, though :(

Comment: @Juan: It shouldn't - did you copy and paste the code directly in? (I see the same error as the OP... and did even before the namespaces were there.)

Comment: @JonSkeet my fault I don't know how I missed the namespaces when copying and pasting it.

Comment: @Juan: The namespaces weren't there before, but they should be irrelevant. The original code without any namespaces failed with the same error. Namespaces have no influence on accessibility.

Comment: @JonSkeet this same thing https://dotnetfiddle.net/AkEaZz compiles for me on VS, as it does on .Net fiddle.

Comment: @Juan: Your class `Y` is internal. The OP's is public. That makes a huge difference. Changing it to `public` within dotnetfiddle doesn't show an error, but I *suspect* that's because it's adding an enclosing `internal` class...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! It wasn't that, I just pasted the code inside the default Program class on my console application on VS. .Net Fiddle still doens't seem to worry about it anyway (even making the class public) :)

Comment: @Juan: Try adding `System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(Y))` and you'll see why - it's a nested type, and I'm pretty sure the type it's nested in is internal. That will stop this error from appearing in almost all cases...

Comment: @Kamen: Not a problem. Searches aren't always great. You found the answer to your question and that's the key thing. For what its worth I found it because it came up on the related links on the right. Its sometimes worth looking there after posting to see what it thinks is related (I've noticed its not always the same questions as when you are writing your question).

Comment: @Chris Thanks :) I opted for an interface and also made a facade `public` class and hid the abstract and child classes